# Joins and grouping issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have four table in my Hospital database. I need to display the names of all patients, and for each patient, the names of the physicians that they visited more than once, along with the number of visits to each of these physicians. If a patient has not visited any physicians, or did not visit any physicians more than once, management does not want to see them in the list. Write a single query that retrieves this information for the management.

```
 Select * from Medical_History;
 Select * from Physician;
 Select * from Appointment;
 Select * from Patient;
```

[image]

I have made join query as well as a group query but i dont know how to combine them. Because i am getting grouping errors. As i need to show the number of visits by the patient to a doctor and it has to be more than one . So help required. Here's the join and group clause:

```
  Select Patient_First_Name,    Patient_Last_Name,Physician_First_Name,Physician_Last_Name
         from Patient Join Medical_History on   Patient.Patient_ID=Medical_History.Patient_ID
        Join Physician on Medical_History.Physician_ID=Physician.Physician_ID;

        select Physician_ID, count(Patient_ID)
        from Medical_History
        Group by Physician_ID, Patient_ID;
```

Comment: please check this link on how to improve question..https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: you could group by patientid, patientname, phyician,physicianname  - in your select you need count(*) as 'numberOfTimesPatentSawConsultant' and you need to do a Having Count(*) > 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can first use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` to get patients and physicians association and then join with each of their master table to get their names.

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  Patient_First_Name,
  Patient_Last_Name,
  Physician_First_Name,
  Physician_Last_Name,
  TotalVisits
FROM Patient P
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Patient_ID, Physician_ID, COUNT(*) as TotalVisits
    FROM Medical_History
    GROUP BY Physician_ID, Patient_ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
) PP ON P.Patient_ID = PP.Patient_ID
INNER JOIN Physician PH ON PH.Physician_ID = PP.Physician_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would `CROSS APPLY` computations to each `Patient` record like below:

```
SELECT Patient_First_Name, Patient_Last_Name,Physician_First_Name,Physician_Last_Name
FROM Patient
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Physician_First_Name,Physician_Last_Name,COUNT(*) TotalVisits
             FROM Medical_History
             JOIN Physician on Medical_History.Physician_ID=Physician.Physician_ID
             WHERE Medical_History.Patient_ID=Patient.Patient_ID
             GROUP BY Physician_First_Name,Physician_Last_Name
             HAVING COUNT(*)>1) T
```

Internal query selects records having more than one association to `Patient`.